# Why is the line printed only yellow despite changing the value in bl?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bios

```
bits 32
main:

    mov ah, 09h
    mov bh, 0
    mov cx, 80
    mov bl, 01110000b
    mov al, ' '
    int 10h

    jmp $

times 512-($-$$) db 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not in 32-bit mode yet, so use `bits 16`.

Also, in protected mode, BIOS functions aren't available. Just so you know and don't attempt calling them when in protected mode.

Comment: how do i change it to unprotected mode?

Comment: You're not in it yet, nothing to change about it.

Answer (score 0):

It is, in fact, the `bits 32` that keeps this from working. You can see what's happening by using ndisasm. Assemble it as-is, and disassemble it with ndisasm. The default for ndisasm is 16 bits, but you can specify `-b16` for clarity. This is what the CPU will "see" if it's in 16-bit mode... which it is. It'll take some more code to switch to 32-bit mode - you'll get to that soon, but the CPU starts up in 16-bit mode (even a 64-bit CPU). To see what the CPU would "see" if/when it's in 32-bit mode, disassemble again with `-b32`. See the difference? Your `mov bl, 01110000b` has disappeared, being "gobbled up" by the `mov cx, 80`! Then try it again without the `bits 32`. You can say `bits 16`, but that's Nasm's default anyway.

There's a subtle difference between telling the assembler `bits 32` and actually having the CPU in 32-bit mode. Ordinarily, this wouldn't cause much trouble (sombody else - the OS - has determined the CPU mode), but in a boot sector it will!

When you get to actually switching the CPU to 32-bit protected mode, at that point - exactly - you will want to tell Nasm `bits 32`.

Lots of information about this at http://www.osdev.org - I recommend it! I also have an example posted to a newsgroup - a long time ago - by Alexey ("Alexei" actually - that's you isn't it?).

Happy bootin',

Frank